# Using Spring JDBC Template - Performance

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Is Spring SimpleJDBCTemplate production grade?

How good is it to use in the high volume (traffic) site? (Lets say 1K hits per second)

What are the choices we have to improve the performance (Connection Pooling, etc) on the Application Level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is production grade.  Your limit at that volume isn't ran JDBC vs Spring JDBC template vs whatever.  Your limit is resources if it is truly 1000 hits per second.  1000 users at the same time is a lot less hits because they they have "think time" rather than continuously hitting your app.

With any database technology, you will need to tune a lot, look at caching and be very aware of resources.  And yes, you absolutely need connection pooling.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking of using `SimpleJDBCTemplate` over pure `JDBC`...go for it! It should definitely give as much performance and help you get rid of most JDBC connection make/break boiler plate code and exception handling etc.

Spring would allow you to configure connection pooling, tuning as you would do using pure JDBC.

Heres an old blog to provide you with performance comparison: http://pramatr.wordpress.com/2008/08/19/spring-jdbctemplate-the-phantom-performance-problem/

Spring has become better since.

Comment: Overall. Not in comparison to JDBC.